# How can I keep the forms of the arrays when I use numpy concatenate or numpy append

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, numpy-ndarray

I had 3 lists and made them into ndarray.

```
o_a = [1,2,3,4,5]            
o_b = [2,4,6,8,10]
o_c = [11,22,33,44,55]
np_a = np.array(o_a)
np_b = np.array(o_b)
np_c = np.array(o_c)
print(np_a)
print(np_b)
print(np_c)

[1 2 3 4 5]
[ 2  4  6  8 10]
[11 22 33 44 55]
```

when I use vstack to join them, their form is not collapsed

```
np.vstack((np_a,np_b))    
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10]])
```

but if I use concatenate or append to combine them, it just became 1darray

```
np.concatenate((np_a,np_b))
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10])
```

Is there a way that the arrays can keep the form? not using reshape after the work.

Comment: What do you mean _keep the form_? Please post your expected (or desired) output.

Comment: Maybe you want to try the following or show the desired output? `np.array([o_a, o_b, o_c])` or `np.dstack((np_a,np_b, np_c))`

Comment: What's wrong with just using `vstack` in this case?

Comment: 'form' is a vague term.  The shape of your arrays is `(4,)`.  `concatenate` produces `(n*4,)` shape, joining the arrays on an existing axis.  `vstack` (and `stack` and `array`) produce a `(n,4)` array, adding a new axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using `numpy.concatenate()` or `numpy.append()`:**

```
np.concatenate((np_a[None,:],np_b[None,:]), axis=0)
```

or

```
np.append(np_a[None,:],np_b[None,:], axis=0)
```

Output (in either case):

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10]])
```

We are now converting each array into a 2-d array before concatenating them both.

And, while concatenating or appending them, we are specifying that the concatenation or appending must happen along `axis=0` (the first axis), of the input arrays.

Note that `numpy.concatenate()` and `numpy.append()` do not create any new dimension. They just concatenate or append along an existing dimension, when you explicitly specify the `axis` argument.

When we don't specify the `axis` argument, the default behavior of `numpy.concatenate()` and `numpy.append()`, is to flatten the input arrays, and also return a flattened array.

---

**Using numpy.stack():**

```
np.stack ((np_a, np_b))
```

This also gives:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10]])
```

Here, we don't have to pre-convert to 2-d. The new dimension will get created by the stacking operation itself.

Note that `numpy.stack()` also takes an `axis` argument, but it defaults to 0, which is what we want.

Also, note that, in the case of `numpy.stack()`, the value that we specify for the `axis` argument, is with respect to the result array (which has one extra dimension), and not with respect to the original input arrays.

Comment: Don't recommend `np.append`. It works here but too often people misuse it, Here `append` can't be used if he tries to join all 3 at once.